# Fast pairwise difference

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

I'm trying to construct a matrix $A_{ij}=X_i-Y_j$ where $X$ and $Y$ are vectors with thousands of real numbers. The fastest and closest thing I found is `DistanceMatrix[X, Y]`, 0.4 seconds for 20000x10000 matrix, but the result only valid if $X_i>Y_j$, otherwise, the sign should be flipped. There is a way to flip sign relatively fast with `LowerTriangularize` (roughly takes another 0.5 seconds), but it works only if $X$ and $Y$ are of the same size. Maybe there is a way to calculate $A_{ij}$ as fast as `DistanceMatrix` does its thing? Or is there a way to quickly flip sign for matrix of arbitrary height and width? Any cycles work very slow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running on an M1 Max (essentially an 8 core machine). Not only does `Compile` compile faster than `FunctionCompile`; it also allows parallelization via OpenMP:

```
f = FunctionCompile[Function[
     {
      Typed[list1, "PackedArray"::["Integer64", 1]],
      Typed[list2, "PackedArray"::["Integer64", 1]]
      },
     Table[i - list2, {i, list1}]],
    UseEmbeddedLibrary -> True
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.6023, Null}

```
cf = Compile[{{a, _Integer}, {b, _Integer, 1}},
    Table[a - Compile`GetElement[b, j], {j, 1, Length[b]}],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.306628, Null}

```
m = 20000;
n = 10000;
a = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, m];
b = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, n];

A = f[a, b]; // RepeatedTiming
B = cf[a, b]; // RepeatedTiming

A == B
```

> {0.225791, Null}
>
> {0.0697286, Null}
>
> True

Alas, you need to have a C compiler installed on your system.

Comment: I am stupid, I upvoted and forgot to ask: do you have any good recommendations for C-compiler for mac? With the apple silicon I mean. Not sure if you would like to include it as part of the reply here or maybe leave a comment in the chat.

Comment: I typically use Apple Clang shipped with XCode. I have never had any serious problems with it. Good alternatives are, of course, the (non-Apple) clang and gcc. You can install both of them with homebrew. All of them produce good code with similar performance. I use Apple Clang because (i) it is nicely integrated in the system and because (ii) it is generally a good idea to use the compiler produced by the hardware manufacturer unless you have good reasons not to do so.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will make sure to give it a try :-)

Comment: Holly, that's fast

Comment: Unfortunately `ParallelTable` is still not supported in `FunctionCompile`...

Answer (score 13):

Two more ways are suggested below. The output is the same as in @Syed's answer.

```
alist = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10];
blist = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 4];
```

Then

```
= # - blist &;
 = Map[Subtract[#, blist] &];
```

and we do

```
/@ alist // MatrixForm
@alist // MatrixForm
```

**Edit 1:** taking the comment by @
Joshua Schrier into consideration, this is even faster

```
foo = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {b, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Map[# - b &, a]];
foo[alist, blist]
```

**Edit 2:** taking the comment by @Ben Izd into consideration, for versions after `12` we can use

```
foo2 = FunctionCompile[
   Function[{Typed[list1, "PackedArray"::["Integer64", 1]], 
     Typed[list2, "PackedArray"::["Integer64", 1]]}, 
    Table[i - list2, {i, list1}]]];
foo2[alist, blist] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: list]

**Edit 3:**

Comparing the [**`RepeatedTimings`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html?v=13.2) of the various approaches so far.

```
$Version
```

> [image: version]

With the lists

```
alist = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 20000];
blist = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10000];
```

we compare the following

```
syed[l1_List, l2_List] := Outer[Subtract, l1, l2](*taking the comment by @Roman into account*)
 = # - blist &;
 = Map[Subtract[#, blist] &];
foo = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {b, _Integer, 1}}, Map[# - b &, a]];
foo2 = FunctionCompile[
   Function[{Typed[list1, "PackedArray"::["Integer64", 1]], 
     Typed[list2, "PackedArray"::["Integer64", 1]]}, 
    Table[i - list2, {i, list1}]]];
```

and now we measure

```
syed[alist, blist]; // RepeatedTiming
 /@ alist; // RepeatedTiming
@alist; // RepeatedTiming
foo[alist, blist]; // RepeatedTiming
foo2[alist, blist]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> [image: timings]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works just as fast as DistanceMatrix.

Comment: @VsevolodA. glad I was able to help :-)

Comment: You can shave off an extra 2-3x time by: 
```
foo = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {b, _Integer, 1}}, Map[# - b &, a]]
foo[alist, blist]
```
(change to `_Real` if you want reals, etc.)

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier very nice observation. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using version 12.0+, you can halve the timing of `Compile` by using `FunctionCompile`: `FunctionCompile[
 Function[{Typed[list1, "PackedArray"::["Integer64", 1]], 
   Typed[list2, "PackedArray"::["Integer64", 1]]},
  Table[i - list2, {i, list1}]
  ]]`

Comment: @BenIzd thanks for the comment. Very nice observation!

Comment: I would rather use ``cf =Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {b, _Integer}},
 Table[Compile`GetElement[a, i] - b, {i, 1, Length[a]}],
 CompilationTarget -> "C",
 RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
 Parallelization -> True,
 RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
 ]``...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher that command I cannot run, unfortunately. Perhaps you want to write it up as a separate answer and include the timings as well? Thanks for the suggestion btw :-)

Answer (score 7):

As Henrik has demonstrated in [his excellent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/280487/17), the good old C compiler interface is still super fast -- the *fastest* if considering the compiling time. But the new compiler (`FunctionCompile`) still stands *some* chance.

We see the high level way `FunctionCompile[..., Table[...], ...]` performs not so well. Intuitively, using `ParallelTable` instead should have accelerated it, except unfortunately that's not supported yet. So we'll have to go a bit lower level and endure some cumbersome code:

```
fparal = FunctionCompile[Function[
         {  Typed[a, "PackedArray"["Integer64", 1]] 
          , Typed[b, "PackedArray"["Integer64", 1]]  }
         ,
         Module[{ca, cb, c, cc, la = Length@a, lb = Length@b}
          , c = Array`NewPackedArray[TypeSpecifier["Integer64"], LiteralType[2], {la, lb}]
          ; ca = Array`GetData[a]
          ; cb = Array`GetData[b]
          ; cc = Array`GetData[c]
          ; Parallel`ParallelDo[ (* <- might use OpenMP`ParallelDo instead *)
               Do[
                  ToRawPointer[cc, i lb + j, FromRawPointer[ca, i] - FromRawPointer[cb, j]]
                  , {j, 0, lb - 1}]
               , {i, 0, la - 1}]
          ; c]
         ]]
```

`20000*10000` is a bit too much for my RAM, so I'll test on smaller example (here `cf` and `f` are directly taken from Henrik's answer):

```
$Version
(* Out[]= 13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 1, 2023) *)

m = 2000;
n = 1000;
a = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, m];
b = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, n];

cf[a, b] == f[a, b] == fparal[a, b]
(* Out[]= True *)

RepeatedTiming[     cf[a, b]; , 5]
RepeatedTiming[      f[a, b]; , 5]
RepeatedTiming[ fparal[a, b]; , 5]
(* Out[]=
   {0.00354544, Null}
   {0.00818736, Null}
   {0.00342079, Null}
*)
```

So `fparal` performs as well as `cf` on my machine with an Intel i7 CPU. It would be interesting to see how `fparal` performs on Apple Silicon though.

Comment: Jepp, I can confirm that `fparal` has pretty much the same timing as `cf` (the `Compile` version) on my Apple M1 Max. God job!

Comment: I'd like to mention that the task at hand is very memory bound which is why not much speed-up can be seen (typical already few CPU cores fully saturate the memory bandwith). Would be cool to see a comparison also for some more compute-intense task...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for your valuable comments! I would surely like to see how the new compiler competes in various compute-intense tasks. Unfortunately I don't have access to cutting-edge powerful computers for that kind of test. Frankly, on my daily work I still mainly use `Compile` because of the incompatible compiling time, also because the still-lack-of-docs status of `FunctionCompile` (like I have to search the source code to guess the usage of `NewPackedArray`).

Comment: All fine. I myself also always use `Compile` and will continue to do so until `FunctionCompile` is more stable and better documented. =) "like I have to search the source code to guess the usage of `NewPackedArray`" Very good. Thank you for you effort!

Answer (score 6):

**Using `Outer`:**

```
alist = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10];
blist = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 4];

{alist, blist}
```

> {{2, 5, 1, 8, 1, 1, 9, 7, 1, 5}, {2, 9, 6, 2}}

```
(res = Outer[(#1 - #2 &), alist, blist]) // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & -7 & -4 & 0 \\
 3 & -4 & -1 & 3 \\
 -1 & -8 & -5 & -1 \\
 6 & -1 & 2 & 6 \\
 -1 & -8 & -5 & -1 \\
 -1 & -8 & -5 & -1 \\
 7 & 0 & 3 & 7 \\
 5 & -2 & 1 & 5 \\
 -1 & -8 & -5 & -1 \\
 3 & -4 & -1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: The issue is it will about 10 times slower than DistanceMatrix.

Comment: `Outer[Subtract, alist, blist]` is easier on the eye.

Comment: A request could be put in for `SignedDistanceMatrix`.

Comment: @Syed signed distance only exists for 1d elements, while `DistanceMatrix` works for any vectors.

Answer (score 5):

It's worth noting that `Outer[Plus, v1, -v2]` is much faster than `Outer[Subtract, v1, v2]`, it's not the fastest, but very simple.

```
m = 20000;
n = 10000;
a = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, m];
b = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, n];

r1 = Outer[Plus, a, -b]; // AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Outer[Subtract, a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming
r1===r2
```

> {0.614791, Null}
> {26.8156, Null}
> True

Henrik's `cf` on my computer

```
cf[a, b]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.218258, Null}

Comment: (+1) This timing difference is so weird that it should be filed as bug report...